# UFT 12.02, Compare two PDF/Word file and display the difference between them

Tags: hp-uft

Can Anyone help me here.
**Task:-** I have to Read Two PDF/Word file and compare them and display the difference between them if any line wise.
**Tool Using**: **UFT 12.02.**

Please Help here

Thanks
Manish Anand

FYI: Although i am able to perform the above task on text file, but not able to perform on PDF/Word file. Please suggest here hoe to perform the task for PDF/Word File.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [file content checkpoint](http://uftquestions.blogspot.co.il/2014/05/qtp-uft-file-content-checkpoint-in-uft.html)?